# Google undetermined malware fix for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-search-console, malware

Just today when I tried to access my site I got a warning saying my site has harmful content.

I have tried scanning the site with clamAV and some other online sites for virus scan but did not find anything. I submitted my site to Google and it is still saying it is malicious. There is no sample URL for the malware, it only says "Undetermined malware"

I am using WordPress, there was no plugin updated recently. How can I find which part of my site is infected?

I tried console of google chrome, tried installing new anti-malware plugin (nothing found), tried to scan the site with different other websites and such but nothing gave any positive result.

Answer (score 1):

Security on a website is very different from security on a home computer. Fixing this will be hard for someone who knows what they are doing, you have a lot of learning to do ahead of you before you will be able to accomplish this effectively. As a first step you need to try to identify when the problem started and revert to an earlier backup. Then remove ALL plugins, upgrade your WordPress installation to the latest version then change all the passwords associated with your site, then ONLY install the absolutely essential plugins - and make sure its the latest production versions of these.

This *might* fix the problem.